# Change the background of ListTile widget to be transparent so that it blends with the color of the background page

Tags: flutter, background, transparent, toggleswitch

I had to create a toggle switch with some text next to it. I thought it was better to do it by using the **ListTile** widget which uses *title* to display the text next to the toggle switch and *leading* to display the switch before the text.
The problem is that when the background of the page changes the **ListTile** background is white.

I can put the listtile widget inside a container and change the color of the container to change the color of the listtile but I don't want to do that because the background changes dynamically and I don't want to change the color of container everytime. Is there any way I can make the listtile transparent so that it gets the color of the background automatically?

As soon in the image, background is yellow but listtile is white and I want it to be yellow.[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NVx2.png).
The code that I have:

```
Scaffold(
 backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        child: ListTile(
          leading:  ToggleSwitch
          title: Text("Account"),
        ),
      )
```

I **cannot** do the following because I can set the background of the scaffold but I **cannot** set the color of the container manually:

```
Scaffold(
 backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
        child: Container(
color : Colors.yellow 
ListTile(
          leading:  ToggleSwitch
          title: Text("Account"),
        ),
      ),
)
```

Is there a way I can achieve this or should I implement without using the **ListTile** widget?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a custom listTile as from [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) ListTile constructors dont take a color

```
 ListTile({Key key, Widget leading, Widget title, Widget subtitle, Widget trailing, bool isThreeLine: false, bool dense, EdgeInsetsGeometry contentPadding, bool enabled: true, GestureTapCallback onTap, GestureLongPressCallback onLongPress, bool selected: false })
```

from the documentation page there is an eample on how to create a custom ListTile

Comment: then how to blend with the background?

Comment: I think transparent color would do best